# Installed package but get older version

Tags: ubuntu, apt, node.js

I've updated NodeJS but the version still displays as the older.
What am I doing wrong? I can see it has downloaded the latest (4.1.2).

[image: Help]

Comment: Pasting text rather than an image is generally preferable.

Answer (score 2):

The output of "which node" shows you are running a local copy.

The debian/ubuntu nodejs packages use the command name "nodejs" not "node". There is a package called "nodejs-legacy" which you can install if you want a binary called "node". You might also want to get rid of the old copy you have installed in /usr/local

Comment: Even if Debian didn't rename node, the default path variable orders /usr/local/bin before /usr/bin, so you would need to remove that anyway.